# How to set (and get) a property that is set in a ViewModel from a ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a `ContentPage` which contains a `CarouselView`. The contentpage has 1 List property (`ActivityData`) that is being used as the `ItemSource`.
The ContentPage makes use of a `ItemTemplate` (`ContentView`) to display different elements. This ContrentView contains the properties that are defined in the 'main' property; `ActivityData`.

What I want to achieve is the following, in my ContentView I have a List of Cards. The ItemSource for this list is the List property '`LocationFloors`', this property is contained in the `ActivityData` property that is defined in the `ViewModel` of the ContentPage.

I have set up a `TapGestureRecognizer` event to catch the 'tap' event on a card of the list. When this happens, the tapped card should change it's background to red, while all other cards in the list should change the background to blue.

I have set up a bit, but I am having trouble with how I can set the value of the `LocationFloors` item while also triggering a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event so that the UI changes.

The `NotifyPropertyChanged` is now implemented in the `ViewModel` itself, but will only trigger when I set / change the `ActivityData` property. Does this mean I have to change the `LocationFloor` item directly in the `ActivityData` property?

How can I access (get / set) the `ActivityData` property, defined in my ViewModel, from my ContentView?

**The ContentView code:**

```
public partial class PCSActivityOverviewTemplate : ContentView
{
    public PCSActivityOverviewTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var model = ((CardView)sender).BindingContext as ActivityFloor;

        if(model.IsSelected == false)
        {
            model.IsSelected = true;
            // Not triggering PropertyChanged... 
        }
    }

}
```

**The ViewModel:**

```
public class ActivityOverviewViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private List<ActivityLocation> activityData;
    private readonly IRoutingService _routingService;

    // The dataSource
    public List<ActivityLocation> ActivityData
    {
        get { return activityData; }
        set { SetProperty(ref activityData, value); }
    }

    public ActivityOverviewViewModel(IRoutingService routingService = null)
        : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
    {
        _routingService = routingService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IRoutingService>();
        LoadData();
    }


    private async void LoadData()
    {
        // Set DataSource of Page
        var _activitiesData = await App.Database.GetActivityDataAsync(DateTime.UtcNow);
        ActivityData = _activitiesData;
    }

}
```

**The ActivityData List model:**

```
public class ActivityLocation 
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; } 
        .. few more properties
        public List<ActivityFloor> LocationFloors { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityFloor
    {
        public int FloorId { get; set; } 
        .. some other properties
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }  // property with which the Backgroundcolor of a Card should change. 
    }
```

Comment: Friendly advice: Please avoid to bypass the system by deleting a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66215337) and re-posting an improved version of it, better opt for [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: I am confused here "in my ContentView I have a List of Cards" I don't see the List you are refering to, probably not ActivityData because it is in the vm and not the ContentView. or you mean ListView ?

Comment: @Cfun yea my bad, I didn't see the reopen button. Yep I mean a ListView, well it is actually a WrapPanel which derives from `Layout<View>`, its ItemSource binding is set to the LocationFloors List property which is contained in the ActivityData property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-icommand) then can get/set `ActivityData` in ViewModel.

For example:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer
        Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
//Item is the x:Name of the Root Layout (such as ListView Cell's ItemTemplate)
```

Then in View Model could get it:

```
    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as ActivityLocation);
                item.backgroundcolor = ...
                // logic on item
                // Here data is ActivityLocation
                foreach (var otheritem in ActivityData)
                {
                    if(item.name == otheritem.name){
                        // do nothing
                    }else{
                        otheritem.backgroundcolor = ...
                    }
                }
            }   
       
    }
```

================================**Update**===================================

From shared sample, the **DemoTestTemplate** will not need bindable properties here:

```
public partial class DemoTestTemplate : ContentView
{

}
```

And its **Xaml** code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="TestDemoAPP.DemoTestTemplate"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>

            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding LabelColor}"
                HeightRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Text="Hello Sir, please click me"
                TextColor="White"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                WidthRequest="200">
            </Label>

        </Grid>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And you need to modify **ActivityModel** model as follows:

```
public class ActivityLocation: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<ActivityLocation> activityLocations { set; get; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityFloor> CurrentFloors { get; set; }

    private Xamarin.Forms.Color labelColor;
    public Xamarin.Forms.Color LabelColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (labelColor != value)
            {
                labelColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LabelColor");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return labelColor;
        }
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as ActivityLocation);
                item.LabelColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;
                // logic on item
                // Here use messagecenter to ViewModel
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, ActivityLocation>(this, "ColorChange", item);
            });
        }
   }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ActivityFloor
{
    public int FloorId { get; set; } 
    public string FloorName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the **DemoTestViewModel** ViewModel modify as follows:

```
public class DemoTestViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public DemoTestViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private List<ActivityLocation> activityData;
    public List<ActivityLocation> ActivityData
    {
        get { return activityData; }
        set { SetProperty(ref activityData, value); }
    }

    private int _position;

    public int Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _position, value); }
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        // SEEDING TEST DATA (2 differtent locations, 5 floors each)

        // Initialize Floors
        var activityFloors_location1 = new List<ActivityFloor>
        {
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 1, FloorName = "(Location 1) Floor 1" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 2, FloorName = "(Location 1) Floor 2" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 3, FloorName = "(Location 1) Floor 3" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 4, FloorName = "(Location 1) Floor 4" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 5, FloorName = "(Location 1) Floor 5" }
        };

        var activityFloors_location2 = new List<ActivityFloor>
        {
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 1, FloorName = "(Location 2) Floor 1" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 2, FloorName = "(Location 2) Floor 2" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 3, FloorName = "(Location 2) Floor 3" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 4, FloorName = "(Location 2) Floor 4" },
            new ActivityFloor { FloorId = 5, FloorName = "(Location 2) Floor 5" }
        };

        // Initialize Locations / merge data
        var activityLocations = new List<ActivityLocation>
        {
            new ActivityLocation {
                LocationId = 1,
                LocationName = "Location 1",
                CurrentFloors = activityFloors_location1,
                LabelColor = Color.Blue
            },
            new ActivityLocation
            {
                LocationId = 2,
                LocationName = "Location 2",
                CurrentFloors = activityFloors_location2,
                LabelColor = Color.Blue
            }
        };

        // Set ListSource for ContentPage's CarouselView
        try
        {
            activityData = activityLocations;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, ActivityLocation>(this, "ColorChange", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            foreach(var item in activityData)
            {
                if(arg.LocationId == item.LocationId)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    item.LabelColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now back to **DemoTestPage** page to modify is **Xaml** code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TestDemoAPP.Views.DemoTestPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDemoAPP"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestDemoAPP.ViewModels">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:DemoTestViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <CarouselView
                x:Name="carousel"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                IsScrollAnimated="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityData}"
                Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame x:Name="Item" Style="{StaticResource CarouselWorkaround}">
                            <local:DemoTestTemplate>
                                <local:DemoTestTemplate.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
                                </local:DemoTestTemplate.GestureRecognizers>
                            </local:DemoTestTemplate>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

            </CarouselView>

            <IndicatorView
                x:Name="indicatorView"
                Padding="0,0,0,30"
                IndicatorColor="{DynamicResource TranslucidBlack}"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}"
                VerticalOptions="Start" />

        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then you will see the effects:

[image]

Comment: Sadly this does not work. After some more investigation I found a post which has (sort of) the same issue; https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113853/custom-control-binding-to-command-in-parent-view-model. It seems that I cannot Bind the properties because the ContentView has a ItemSource / ItemTemplate as it's parent in the ContentPage. I created a small DEMO repo with some some `BindableProperty` to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/nicolasHul/DemoAPPXamarin

Comment: @Nicolas Hi, maybe you didn't get my opinion. I will update in my answer, and I have modified the sample then make it works.